# fastest way to add a click handler to elements being added to the dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let us say we are adding several elements to the dom. What is the best way to make sure these elements also have a click handler added to them? For example, if I have a click handler on all elements with the class "canvas-section", and I keep adding "canvas-section" elements, what is the best way to make sure in Jquery that these new "canvas-section" elements also have that click handler added.

Before I used to use the "live" jquery function or "on" but those don't seem to work for elements that are dynamically added or added after the original click listener is added.

Comment: There is no "best" way.  You can either do a direct binding on them, or make a delegate event handler on the parent of the dynamic children.  Either way works.  Asking for the "best" way is looking for an opinionated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the click handler to a parent object, including `document`, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.div-to-click', function() {
    console.log('hi!');
});
```

See: https://api.jquery.com/on/